# Use SED to replace text in a XML with the contents of another file

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to search and replace "      REPLACEME" with the contents of /tmp/dictionary.txt using SED.

I've tried a few other solutions mentioned on stack overflow, however they keep throwing errors:
sed: 3: "#      REPLACEME

Thank you!

script I'm using:

```
#!/bin/bash


sed '#          <string>REPLACEME</string># {
r /tmp/dictionary.txt
}' /tmp/plaintext.plist > palintext_ammended.plist
```

Comment: Do you know or care whether the contents of the "plain text" file are well-formed XML?  If not, this question has nothing to do with XML.

Comment: I'm using this script as a part of a larger one. I'm injecting a list of favorite servers into com.applesidebar.plist. Checks via tidy/plutil are run before and after to make sure the XML format is valid. I was attempting to deflect any statements about needing to convert between binary1/xml1 formats by calling it plaintext.xml.... Also it implied the presence of XML code which can screw up SED if basic substitution is used: sed s/pattern/`cat /tmp/dictionary.txt`/g /tmp/plaintext.plist. I appreciate the comment just the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
sed -e '/<string>REPLACEME<\/string>/r /tmp/dictionary.txt' -e '//d' /tmp/plaintext.plist
```

sed only allows alternative delimiter for `s` (substitute) command. With `#` it will ignore rest of the command probably treating that as comment.

Comment: That code appears to append the text from /tmp/dictionary.txt right after <string>REPLACEME<\/string>. Is there a way to replace it? I can follow it up with a command to delete line afterwards if not.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/REPLACEME/{s//\n/;P;e cat dict.txt' -e 'D}' plain.txt
```